# Cypher to sum the weight of all incoming edges to a particular node in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I want to get the summarized weight of all incoming edges to a particular node in neo4j For eg. S. Keshav has to incoming weighted edge , first having **weight =2** and second having **weight=4** , I need **answer=6**

[image: Sample data model]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using the [sum()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/#functions-sum) function:

```
match ()-[r]->({name : 'S. Keshav'})
return sum(r.weight)
```